# Using URLs as argument for command and for output file name

Tags: command-line, bash, bash-scripting

Im trying to use either XARGS or FOR in a single line to accept a list of **URLS** as arguments, this fails since a file name can't be a URLs. We tried doing this with FOR and XARGS, but it fails:

```
$for i in $(cat example.txt);do echo $i > $i; done
bash: http://example.site.com: No such file or directory
bash: https://secureexample.com: No such file or directory

$cat example.txt | xargs -I {} sh -c "echo  {} > {}"
sh: 1: cannot create http://example.site.com: Directory nonexistent
sh: 1: cannot create https://secureexample.com: Directory nonexistent
```

is it possible to remove the forward slashes from the argument in the second occurrence(name of the output file) so that ill get a distinctive file per host, for example:

```
http.example.site.com
https.secureexample.com
```

My knowledge in single-line bash is pretty limited, sadly, that's the company's preference. 
i tried using curly braces on the filename and change the value with SED, AWK and even CUT, but as i said, my knowledge is too limited. I also tried multiple arguments with XARGS and FOR but i also failed spectacularly to make that work.

I was able to circumvent the issue by creating separate files with **URIs** instead of **URLs**, and then supplement http:// and https://, but that means double the files and double the commands, example:

```
$cat http_example.txt
example.site.com
secureexample.com 
$cat http_example.txt | xargs -I {} sh -c "echo  http://{} > {}"
$ls -la
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   24 Mar 22 08:06 example.site.com
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   25 Mar 22 08:06 secureexample.com
```

Is there **any** way to make this work in a single line bash command whilst using a file with URLS?
thank you!

Comment: Difficult to understand what is your question. Can you make it clearer?

Comment: I edited it, i hope that makes it clearer. i may need to edit the title as well, but i can't figure out a way to explain it properly.

Comment: Yes, I think I get it now. Do you really need the leading `http(s).` in the resulting file name? Or would `example.site.com` be enough?

Comment: Yes, i can do it without (see the circumvent portion). All of the tools we use in my company need complete URLS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while read -r i;do echo "$i">"${i#http*://}";done<example.txt
```

This removes the leading `http(s)://` part, creating `example.site.com` and `secureexample.com` files.

The `${i#http*://}` is a construct that removes from `$i` the leading part matching `http*://` (`*` is a wildcard).

---

```
while read -r i;do echo "$i">"$(echo "$i"|sed 's|://|.|')";done<example.txt
```

This one creates files `http.example.site.com` and `https.secureexample.com`.

The `sed` is replacing `://` of the input file lines with `.`.

Comment: It works wonderfully, my machine was acting up. it works very well, thank you so much.

Comment: i see what went wrong, if there is a / at the end of the URL im getting errors, is this fixable? even if not that's fine ofcourse

Comment: Yes! In the last command, just change the second `$i` → `${i%/}` (right before `sed`).

Comment: First of all, thank you. you can stop answering whenever you want, you've done more than enough.  i need just a tiny bit more help with the SED part. it doesn't work with hosts that reside on other ports, so https://website.com:8080 wont work. again, fill free to stop answering you have done more than enough

Comment: Glad to help! What exactly do you mean with doesn't work? It creates the file `website.com:8080`, you want it without `:8080`?